# WinForms to acquire Cell Tower information

Tags: c#, .net, geolocation, cell

I am designing a monitoring application on Windows 7. What it does is to record the longitude and latitude of the laptop every 5 seconds. A simple method involves connecting a dedicated GPS device to the laptop's USB port and sampling the ie. COM5 port for a $GPGGA string.

However, I have recently acquired a Dell Latitude E6420 with 3G & A-GPS support. Considering that it as a 3G data connection, I am able to capture my location based on Wifi networks around using Google's GeoLocation JSON as described in [The Project Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63747/Exploring-GoogleGears-Wi-Fi-Geo-Locator-Secrets).

In the unfortunate events that there are no wireless networks around, I was wondering if I can use the cell towers to determine my location instead. The way to do so should either be grabbing the cell tower information from the 3G Network Card built into the laptop or via a 3G USB Dongle.

I have seen several projects to achieve this on mobile phones running Android or iOS, also using the [Radio Interface Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920475.aspx) to achieve that goal. I also found a wrapper that enables me to use this via C# .NET but they are mainly for CE or CF.

Can anyone advise me where should I go about to achieve these cell tower information on WinForms C#.NET so I can send it to JSON to grab my location? Or are there some alternatives to go around to achieve this same goal?

Thank you.

Comment: It's been a while since I posted this question. Since then, I've found a workaround but if there's anyone with a solution, kindly let me know. Thank you.